# retrieve multiple values from sqlite database and populate it in listview in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hae stackoverflow gurus,

I'm looking for an assistance. i have researched all over the internet but in vain. I would like to add all values fetched to listview. I have managed to insert values to the database and managed to fetch all of them however, i'm unable to add them to listview.
The function below works perfect and returns the data as list.

```
 public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

Also, the function below works perfect and prints out all the retrieved values using log

```
}


 private void showRecords() {

        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

        for (Contact cn : contacts) {

            //lv.setAdapter(new dataAdapter(this, cn.getID(), cn.getName(), cn.getPhoneNumber()));
            String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
            // Writing Contacts to log
            //Log.d("Name: ", log);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),log, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Now, i have created a listview for which is working however, i'm unable to add  data to the listview as shown.

```
 private void showRecords() {

            List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

           for(int i=0; i < contacts.size();i++){
                lv.setAdapter(new dataAdapter(this, cn.getID(),cn.getName(), cn.getPhoneNumber()));
          }         
    }
```

My question is, how can i populate  `List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();` to the listview lv?

This is the entire dataAdapter class

```
public class dataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String [] name;
    String [] phone;
    int [] dataId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public dataAdapter(Context context, int[] dataId, String[] name, String[] phone){

        this.context=context;
        this.dataId=dataId;
        this.name=name;
        this.phone=phone;

        inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return dataId.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public  class  Holder{
        TextView nameV;
        TextView phoneV;
    }

    public  View getView(final  int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.thelist, null);

        holder.nameV=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        holder.phoneV=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);


        holder.nameV.setText(name[position]);
        holder.phoneV.setText(phone[position]);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context,name[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        return  rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial follow this tutorial for custom adapter

Comment: Your `showRecords` method is wrong. You don't loop through the records and set the adapter for each one. You should create a _single instance_ of an Adapter backed by your `List<Contact>` and then set it _once_

Comment: Please David, can you do it for me because i'm totally confused

Comment: jhamas, thanks for the link however i want to populate the data in list to the listview. The listview works perfect, big problem is how to add the data to the listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set the adapter for every new item, instead pass the list of contacts to list view adapter only once. And if you want to add new item add the add to existing adapter.

You can do like this

```
private void showRecords() {
   List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
   lv.setAdapter(new dataAdapter(this, contacts));       
}
```

Or you follow the tutorial provided in comment above for better understanding.

**Edit 1**
Instead of taking array of every field of your contact class, take a list of contact, which you have from `List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts()`

```
.....
.....
List<Contact> mContacts;

DataAdapter(Context context,List<Contact> contact) {
    this.context=context;
    this.mContacts=contacts;  
    .....
    .....  
}
```

Your getCount method should be

```
public int getCount() {
    return mContact.size();
}
```

And your getView() method should be

```
public  View getView(final  int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Contact contact = mContact.get(position);
    ....
    ....
    holder.nameV.setText(contact.getName());
    holder.phoneV.setText(contact.getPhone());
    ....
    ....
    return view;
}
```

And if you add to this existing adapter, add a custom method like this

```
public void add(Contact contact) {
    if(mContact != null) {
        mContact.add(contact);
        // This will refresh the list.
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I would still suggest you to go through the tutorial mention in the link above, your adapter class needs lot of changes for better implmentation.

Comment: Still not working, the setAdapter() class has four params

Comment: three of the four param makes Contact object, so you can modify the adapter to take a list of contact instead. Like `DataAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts)`

Comment: I see you have a clue, can i post the entire listAdapter ?

Comment: I have posted the entire dataAdapter class. See the edits

Comment: it has worked however, it is returning a list with data info.example.androidsqlitedb.Contacts@32c445a7

Comment: OMG, you saved me, you deserve 100 upvotes ... I worked over this issue for more than a week ... Perfect working. And what about the last function, were will i add it?

Comment: in your adapter class itself